# How to export variable [in Makefile, shell script, ...] to be seen as defined in C (as macro)?

Tags: c, makefile, macros, c-preprocessor

I wrote two simple functions which use `md4` from `openssl` and `md4` from `crytpo++`. Now, I want to make the code more 'portable' and be able to use the function depending on which library (`openssl` or `crypto++`) user has installed. I know how to check if libs are installed, simply:

```
dpkg --status $openssl | grep -q not-installed

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "OpenSSL is not installed."
fi
```

But how can I export such information to be seen in C code? Something like:

```
dpkg --status $openssl | grep -q not-installed

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    export has_openssl=false
fi
```

and then, in **C** code:

```
#if !defined has_openssl
use function from cryptopp
#else
use function from openssl
#endif
```

Is that possible? If so, how can I do this? In my previous question, [How to check if openssl or cryptopp is installed and use the library that actually exists in the system (is installed)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310353/how-to-check-if-openssl-or-cryptopp-is-installed-and-use-the-library-that-actual), user @MattMcNabb suggested the solution but I'm not quite familiar with the Makefile part he mentioned about.

Comment: Why are you willing to make the assumption that `dpkg` is installed?

Comment: `man autoconf`.  It's a bit of a read.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Huh, good point. I think its the easiest way to check if something is installed and that is why I used it here. So what should I do in case I dont have dpkg?

Comment: You want a way to detect libraries. And then how to cope, when that tool isn't available. And then to compile code accordingly. And then to compile a multiplicity of files using a tool with which you are not familiar. This site is for specific question, not complex solutions to general problems; I suggest you hire a programmer on the [job board](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 2):

I presume that you have to call your compiler from your shell script.

You can use the following for a simple define:

```
gcc -Dhas_openssl
```

or an undefine:

```
gcc -Uhas_openssl
```

For more complex defines, you can use for instance:

```
gcc -Dname=\"John\"
```

This means that you can call your compiler as (of course, you must mention the source file name in the gcc compiler line):

```
dpkg --status $openssl | grep -q not-installed

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    gcc -Uhas_openssl
else
    gcc -Dhas_openssl
fi
```

You can then use the first define as

```
#if !defined has_openssl
  use function from cryptopp
#else
  use function from openssl
#endif
```

***Edited for Yak:***

You can do exactly the same from the makefile as from the script:

```
gcc -Dhas_openssl
```

or

```
gcc -Uhas_openssl
```

You can make an initial makefile with all the gcc statements with a "stub" parameter. For instance:

```
gcc ***param1*** source.c
gcc ***param1*** anotherSource.c
gcc ***param1*** yetAnOtherSource.c
```

Then, from your script, just before launching your makefile, change

```
***param1***
```

in -Dhas_openssl or in -Uhas_openssl.

Comment: Thats a brilliant and simple solution, however, in fact, my application will be (in future) a program which consists of lots of files ... So, I can't use a simple gcc here, I would rather use a multiline Makefile

Comment: @yak: This looks to me like a good answer to your question; if it isn't, then it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: There's nothing magical at all about makefiles. Regardless of whether or not you use GNU autotools, you should do the configure/make style of building. Create a configure shell script that generates a makefile, and in the generated makefile, set the variable CRYPTOLIB (or similar) to either OPEN_SSL or CRYPTOPP. Then wherever you invoke gcc in the makefile, add -D$(CRYPTOLIB) to the call. That will define it for you in the C code.